# Move contents of folder to new folder named by timestamp

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I need to move the contents of a folder say `C:\MyContent` to another folder say `C:\April-13-03_163000`. The destination folder should be created at the time of move based on the timestamp. The format of the folder should be `MONTH-YY-DD_HHMMSS`.

I have created a batch script for with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%b-%%c-%%a)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a)
mkdir C:\%mydate%_%mytime%
move C:\MyContent\*.* C:\%mydate%_%mytime%\ /y
```

But the above script is creating the folder as `04-2013-03_1630`. How to get the desired naming format?

Comment: See [How to print month name in file name by using bat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469307/how-to-print-month-name-in-file-name-by-using-bat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler way would be adding the following:

```
if %bb%==01 set bb=January
if %bb%==02 set bb=February
....
```

and so on before the `set mydate=%%b-%%c-%%a` command. There are probably more neat solutions, but this should be good.